# Literally odd smoothing issue in PDF Preview

Tags: pdf, preview, font

I have an odd smoothing issue with Preview in MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 on my retina MBP. Every right-hand (odd-numbered) page is very blurry, almost unreadable, while the left hand pages are somewhat blurry, but not quite as badly so (see screen capture below).

This happened suddenly, in the middle of a work session, there were no problems just moments before the issue suddenly occurred. I do not see similar blurriness on other viewers (Acrobat, Skim). The blur occurs both on the built-in retina screen and on my 1920x1200 monitor.

I decided to turn off font smoothing, but that option is now gone from the Settings window (when did this happen?)

What can be causing this weird behaviour?

[image]

**Update:** The smoothing issue persisted through several reboots, but has now disappeared.

Comment: Not to be an Apple naysayer, but I feel like Preview has become increasingly buggy recently (High Sierra even moreso, but not relevant here.) This occurs for all documents, correct?

Comment: Yes, at least for the few that I've tried.

Comment: Weird, it almost looks like the right half just isn't scaled properly to the display.

Comment: Yes, it almost looks worse than just a smoothing thing.

Comment: Have you tried viewing it in single page mode?

Comment: There is an option to use LCD font smoothing when available. It is in system preferences/general at the very bottom of window. I don't know if this even applies to your problem but mentioned it in case it did.

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned in my update, the issue disappeared after several reboots. But you're saying that there is a system wide font smoothing setting, but not a setting in Preview specifically?